# C# draw box set cursor

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to draw a box in a console but I cant figure out to do it without entering a new line.

I make something like this:

```
-----
|   |
_____
```

But the input line comes directly underneath it and removing the upper row of the box.

I tried with `Console.setCursorPosition` but the last line is already filled thus already a new line created.

How can I prevent the new line from being created?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
It is possible to use the console window as a canvas?
Lets assume a window with the following size

Height : 50
Width  : 100

I can place any character on any of the tiles within the above given console size.

Would this be possible if so how?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted code you wrote to create this box from ASCII chars. If you use `Console.WriteLine()`, maybe just try to use `Console.Write()` method instead. I've made a quick test and the extra line seems not to be created.

Comment: I indeed use Console.Write() however if the end of the line is met a new line will be created, I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted code you wrote to create this box from ASCII chars.

If you use `Console.WriteLine()`, just use `Console.Write()` method for the last line instead. So, for the box in your question the code can look like:

```
...
Console.WriteLine("-----");
Console.WriteLine("|   |");
Console.Write("-----");
...
```

Let me know if this helps.

I made a test in a sample application and the extra line seems not to be created.

**Update**

If you want to use the box a border to the Console window, I suppose it would be ***the easiest solution*** (if not the only one) not to add the last ***-*** character in the bottom line of the box you are drawing.

**Update II**

You can try to use a simple trick and dynamically change height of the console window before drawing the last line. This will prevent the window from being scrolled.

Try  code like this:

```
int width = Console.WindowWidth;
int height = Console.WindowHeight;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
    Console.Write("-");
}

for (j = 0; j < height - 2; ++j)
{
    Console.Write("|");

    for (i = 0; i < width - 2; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.Write("|");
}

//enlarge window in order to prevent it from being scrolled
Console.WindowHeight += 1;

for (i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
    Console.Write("-");
}
//restore window's original size
Console.WindowHeight -= 1;
//set cursor inside the border
Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 1);
```

This should allow you to get the whole border visible in the window.

**Update III**

**The suggested solution**

Use the code above, but with `Console.BufferWidth` instead of `Console.WindowHeight`. It seems to work correctly and does not require to modify window's dimensions.

Comment: I use Console.Write() and I repeat it for the width of the line.

Comment: Why do you repeat for the width of the line? Could you explain? You question suggested youwant a small box. Do you want it to be something like a border to the  console window? If that's so, I suppose you just have to omit the last ' **-** ' character in the lower row of the border. I suppose that otherwise a new line is created at the moment you insert it.

Comment: I cant insert a character and prevent the next line from being created?

Comment: It seems you can by playing with console's window height. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that very similair task have guys in Microsoft.
Have a look:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx
There's something very similair. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

```
Console.Write("\b\b");
```

This should remove last '\r\n' characters for new line.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about preventing a new line from being created.

Comment: Not sure if it does but the top border has already been wiped out. Even if this does work it unfortunately doesn't solve my problem.